# How can I migrate from Elementary OS to Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: gnome, elementary

I’ve been using Elementary OS for a while now, but I want to try GNOME Shell 3.10, and from what I’ve read Ubuntu 13.10 is required. Since Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 12.10, I won’t be able to try GNOME Shell 3.10 in Elementary OS. So, how can I migrate to Ubuntu 13.10 without loosing my data?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed your `/home` in a separated partition, just select "Something else..." in the Ubuntu installation, then select the `/home` partition, and mark it as **do not format**. Select your `/` partition and use it as `/`. Then continue the installation.

### Do backups as well.

In any other case, do backups and reinstall bottom-up